# Setting specified pins in avr assembly as outputs

Tags: assembly, avr

I am trying to solve the question below for the two blank lines of code and I am starting to confuse myself. Can anyone help me with what code should be filled in and why so.

Assume that pins 4 and 2 on PORTA are connected to an additional output device (DevD). Fill in lines 1-2 such that the corresponding pins are specified as outputs. Do not configure any other pins on the port as outputs.

```
.include “m128def.inc”
.def mpr = r16
START:
.org $0000
   JMP INIT
.org $0004
   RCALL ISR_DevA
   RETI
.org $000C
   RJMP ISR_DevB 
   NOP 
.org $0010
   RJMP ISR_DevC
INIT:
   ldi mpr, 0b00110000
   sts EICRA, mpr
   ldi mpr, 0b11101000
   out EICRB, mpr
   ldi mpr, 10100010
   out EIMSK, mpr
   ldi mpr, $00
   out DDRD, mpr 
   out DDRE, mpr 
   (1) ________________
   (2) ________________
   sei
   ...
```

Comment: What is causing you problem? Just write the appropriate binary value to `DDRA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify pin as output or input in AVR microController by writing to a register called `DDRx` (Data Direction Register)

for every pin in port A there is a corresponding bit in `DDRA` register Control if this pin is work as output or input (1 mean output, 0 mean input)

to make pins 4 and 2 on `PORTA` as ouptut you have to put '1' in corresponding bit this mean you have to write the value `0b00010100` in register 'DDRA'

```
ldi r16, 0b00010100 ; put the value in r16 register
out DDRA, r16       ;write to the DDRA the value in r16
```